# probemod subscript out of bounds

Tags: r

I am trying to probe a moderated relationship, but I keep getting the following error:

```
Error in cov[interactionterm, interactionterm] : subscript out of bounds
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong? Reproducible example:

```
library(probemod)
set.seed(42)
DV<-sample(1:10,20,replace=T)
IV<-sample(1:10,20,replace=T)
MOD<-sample(1:10,20,replace=T)
model<-lm(DV~IV+MOD)
jn(model, dv='DV', iv='IV', mod='MOD')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me it looks like a bug in the package. If you look at the jn function, there is an error in indexing a covariance matrix:

```
   interactionterm <- paste(jnret$iv, jnret$mod, sep = ":")
    jna <- tcrit^2 * cov[interactionterm, interactionterm] - 
      beta.hat[interactionterm]^2
```

`interactionterm` will have the string `"IV:MOD"` assigned in your case. This is obviously not a correct index and the same error occurs when running the example in the `jna` help. Even when repairing this line, another error appears.

I would write to the maintainer of the package.

Comment: I have emailed the package maintainer, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

replace`model<-lm(DV~IV+MOD)` with `model<-lm(DV~IV*MOD)`, may fix the problem.